# Samsung Galaxy A52s (Android 13) has been playing the default ringtone for the past month twice (sometimes more) a day

Tags: samsung, ringtone

My Samsung Galaxy A52s (Android 13) has been playing the default ringtone for the past month twice (sometimes more) a day.

I've tried checking the [Nice Catch](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.app.goodcatch) module that helps keep records of what apps make what sounds but it doesn't show up there. I've also tried checking the permissions manager to see what apps have used the phone app permission they have to trigger the ring, but that also was a dead end.

How to identify the source of the sound?